# How to make lua search modules that are in the same folder with the module in which require is called first?

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

say I've a project folder like:

```
mxn:lab axn$ tree .
.
├── lib
│   ├── a.lua
│   └── b.lua
└── main.lua
```

where `main.lua`:

```
require("lib.a")
```

and in `a.lua` I just use the string `"b"`, trying to tell lua - find a file whose name is `b.lua` in the same folder of `a.lua` first:

```
require("b")
```

and `b.lua`:

```
print('b loaded!')
```

then I run command `lua main.lua` and get error:

```
[Running] lua "/Users/axn/lab/main.lua"
lua: ./lib/a.lua:1: module 'b' not found:
    no field package.preload['b']
    no file './b.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/b.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/b/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/b.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/b/init.lua'
    no file './b.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/b.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ./lib/a.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /Users/axn/lab/main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

I know solutions like `package.path = package.path..';'..'lib/?.lua'`, but what if the structure changes to:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── lib
│       ├── a.lua
│       └── b.lua
└── main.lua
```

I don't want to modify the package.path again. No matter what the structrue is, `require("b")` in `a.lua` will always make lua to search `b` in the same folder of `a.lua` first.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't do that. Using `.` in require is meant for submodules, but neither `a` nor `b` are *submodules* of some `lib` module; that's just where you're putting your modules to keep them organized.

[`package.path`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) exists for exactly this reason. You can just do something like this:

```lua
package.path = './lib/?.lua;./lib/?/init.lua;' .. package.path
```

And Lua will now search for modules in the `lib` directory (in addition to where it usually does).

You can also use the `LUA_PATH` environment variable to do this before even starting Lua.

---

Otherwise, if you *really* don't want to use the "proper" way of using `package.path`, try putting this at the top of `a.lua`:

```lua
print(...)
```

and it should print something like

```
lib.a ./lib/a.lua
```

That should get you to how you want it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rewriting `require` and affecting the behavior of all code everywhere, it's best to create a special function for this purpose:

```
--Utility function for Lua 5.1, which table.pack can do in 5.2+
function pack_params(...)
    return {n = select("#", ...), ...}
end

local curr_local_path = ""

function require_local_path(local_path, ...)
    --Store the old paths on the stack.
    local old_path = package.path
    local old_local_path = curr_local_path

    --Build the new search path and add it to the front of the package.path.
    curr_local_path = curr_local_path .. local_path
    package.path = "./" .. curr_local_path .. "?.lua;" .. package.path

    --Perform the require, storing the results temporarily.
    local rets = pack_params(require(...))

    --Fix the prior paths.
    package.path = old_path
    curr_local_path = old_local_path

    return unpack(rets, 1, rets.n)
end
```

Note that this function forces you to separate the local path from the name of the module being required. The given `local_path` is always expected to be local to the most recent nested call of `require_local_path`. It is also expected to end in a `/` directory separator character.

If you absolutely must give it a single string rather than a separate path, I'm sure you can write a version of this which splits the given module into a base name and a local path.